# Draw Rectangle and Polygon In Squsih

Tags: squish

How to draw a rectangle, ellipse, circle and polygon using mouse press and mouse release  or mouse drag in Squish.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the functions [`mousePress`](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#mousePress-function), [`mouseMove`](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#mouseMove-function) and [`mouseRelease`](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#mouseRelease-function).

You could describe all those shapes as a sequence of points, e.g. clockwise. So a rectangle at position 150/200 which is 300 pixels wide and 100 pixels high might be described as

```
rectangle = [(150,200), (450,200), (450,300), (150, 300)]
```

You could then feed this list of points to a generic function 'drawShape' or so which draws the shape, something like this (in Python, but the same thing can be done in any other of the scripting languages supported by Squish):

```
def drawShape(shape):
    firstPoint = shape[0]

    # Press mouse button at first position
    mousePress(firstPoint[0], firstPoint[1], MouseButton.PrimaryButton)

    # Call mouseMove repeatedly for all subsequent positions
    for x in range(1, len(shape)):
        mouseMove(shape[x][0], shape[x][1])

    # Close the shape by connecting last with the first position
    mouseMove(firstPoint[0], firstPoint[1])

    # Release mouse button to finish drawing
    mouseRelease()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It was very helpful